# Si no hay resultados muestrame otra cosa

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estoy  haciendo un filtrador, pero necesito que cuando no coincida me salga un div por ejemplo diciendo, no hay resultados.

Mi código que viene del AJAX:

$tipo = $_POST['tipoVivienda'];

```
$pob = $_POST['poblacion'];
$dist = $_POST['distrito'];
$tipoContrato = $_POST['tipoContrato'];
$barrio = $_POST['barrio'];
$pvpMax = $_POST['pvpMax'];
$habitaciones = $_POST['habitaciones'];
$aseos = $_POST['aseos'];
$banos= $_POST['banos'];



$tipo1 = "";
$pob1 = "";
$dist1 = "";
$tipoContrato1 = "";
$barrio1 = "";
$pvpMAx1 = "";
$habitaciones1 = "";
$aseos1 = "";
$banos1 = "";


if ($tipo) {
  $tipo1= "AND vi.tipo_id = $tipo";
}
if ($pob) {
  $pob1= "AND vi.localidad = $pob";
}
if ($dist) {
  $dist1= "AND vi.distrito = $dist";
}
if ($tipoContrato) {
  $tipoContrato1= "AND vi.estado_id = $tipoContrato";
}
if ($barrio) {
  $barrio1= "AND vi.barrio = $barrio ";
}
if ($pvpMax) {
  $pvpMax1= "AND (vi.precio < $pvpMax) ";
}
if ($habitaciones == 1) {
  $habitaciones1= "AND (vi.habitaciones = $habitaciones)";
}
if ($habitaciones == 2) {
  $habitaciones1= "AND (vi.habitaciones = $habitaciones)";
}
if ($habitaciones == 3) {
  $habitaciones1= "AND (vi.habitaciones >= $habitaciones)";
}

if ($aseos == 1) {
  $aseos1= "AND (vi.aseos = $aseos)";
}
if ($aseos == 2) {
  $aseos1= "AND (vi.aseos = $aseos)";
}
if ($aseos == 3) {
  $aseos1= "AND (vi.aseos >= $aseos)";
}

if ($banos == 1) {
  $banos1= "AND (vi.banos = $banos)";
}
if ($banos == 2) {
  $banos1= "AND (vi.banos = $banos)";
}
if ($banos == 3) {
  $banos1= "AND (vi.banos >= $banos)";
}
```

Imprimo los resultados:

```
<div id="res">
      <?php
      $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT vi.tipo_id, vi.vivienda_id, vi.localidad, vi.ciudad, vi.nombre, vi.foto, vi.estado_id, vi.etiqueta_id, vi.precio, vi.distrito, vi.conectado,
      vi.metros, vi.habitaciones, vi.aseos, vi.banos, vi.descripcion, et.etiqueta_id, et.etiqueta AS nombreETQ, es.estado_id, es.estado, pb.poblacion_id, pb.poblacion, dis.distrito
      FROM vivienda AS vi
      LEFT JOIN  etiqueta AS et ON vi.etiqueta_id = et.etiqueta_id
      INNER JOIN estado AS es ON vi.estado_id = es.estado_id
      left JOIN poblacion AS pb ON vi.localidad = pb.poblacion_id
      left JOIN distrito AS dis ON vi.distrito = dis.distrito_id WHERE vi.conectado = 1  $tipo1 $pob1 $dist1 $tipoContrato1 $barrio1 $pvpMax1 $habitaciones1 $aseos1 $banos1 ");


       foreach ($results as $i => $res):
       $viID = $res['vivienda_id'];
       $met = $res['metros'];
       $precio = $res['precio'];
       $etiqueta = $res['etiqueta_id'];
       $nombreETQ = $res['nombreETQ'];
       $banos = $res['banos'];
       $aseos = $res['aseos'];
       $distrito = $res['distrito'];{
       ?>

       <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-xl-12">
         <div class="col-12 cuadroPisos cr-cuadroPisos padcero" style="text-align: left;">
           <?php
            if (isset($etiqueta))
              {
                echo "<p class=\"pLab$etiqueta\">¡ $nombreETQ !</p>";
              };
           ?>
           <div class="row">
             <div class="col-5">
               <div class="fotosPisos356" style="background: url(images/pisos/<?php echo $res['foto'] ?>) no-repeat center center;background-size: cover;">
                 <?php
                 if ($res['metros'] == null) {

                 ?>
                 <div class="etiqueta-todos356">
                   <?php
                     if ($res['estado_id'] ==1 || $res['estado_id'] == 2 ) {
                       echo "$precio €/mes";
                     }else {
                       echo "$precio €";
                     }
                    ?>
                 </div>
               <?php }
                 else {

                 ?>
                 <div class="etiqueta-todos">
                   <?php
                     if ($res['estado_id'] ==1 || $res['estado_id'] == 2 ) {
                       echo "$precio €/mes";
                     }else {
                       echo "$precio €";
                     }
                    ?>
                 </div>
                 <?php
                 if ($res['metros'] == null) {
                   echo "";
                 }else {
                   echo "<div class=\"etiqueta-todos etiqueta-metros \"><b> $met<span class=\"font12\">m</span></b><span class=\"sub\">2</span></div>";
                 }
                 ?>
               <?php } ?>

               <?php
                 if ($res['localidad'] == 263) {
                   echo "<div class=\"etiqueta-todos etiqueta-zona \"><b>$distrito</b></div>";
                 }else {
                   echo "";
                 }
                ?>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-7 ">
               <p class="ciudad2"><?php echo $res['poblacion'] ?> (<?php echo $res['ciudad'] ?>)</p>
               <p class="calle2"><?php echo substr($res['nombre'], 0, 50)  ?></p>
               <div class="col-12"><div class="col-12 bordeGris2"></div></div>
               <p class="describePiso2 marbotcero"><?php echo substr($res['descripcion'], 0, 160) ?>...</p>
               <!-- hasta aqui--->
               <div class="col-12 opcionMasinfo2">
                 <ul class="list-inline-item ulPisos2">
                   <?php
                   if ($res['tipo_id'] == 2 || $res['tipo_id'] == 3 ) {
                     echo "<li style=\"list-style:none; height:15px;\"></li>";
                   }else {

                   ?>
                   <li class="list-inline-item pvp" style="font-family: sans-serif;"><img src="images/svg/open-exit-door.svg" alt="" class="imgDoor"> <?php echo $res['habitaciones'] ?> </li>
                   <li class="list-inline-item pvp" style="font-family: sans-serif;margin-left: 4px;"><img src="images/svg/toilet-.svg" alt="" class="imgDoor" style="margin-right: 4px;">
                   <?php
                      if ($res['aseos'] == null) {
                        echo "0";
                      }else{
                        echo "$aseos";
                      }
                    ?>
                    </li>
                   <li class="list-inline-item pvp" style="font-family: sans-serif;margin-left: 6px;">
                   <img src="images/svg/banos.svg" alt="" class="imgDoor" style="margin-right: 4px;">
                     <?php
                        if ($res['banos'] == null) {
                          echo "0";
                        }else{
                          echo "$banos";
                        }
                      ?>
                   </li>
                 <?php } ?>
                 </ul>
                 <div class="target"><?php echo $res['estado'] ?></div>
                 <?php
                    if ($res['tipo_id'] == 1) {
                      echo "<a href=\"detalle-vivienda.php?ID=$viID\" class=\"botonMasInfo pull-right\">MÁS INFO</a>";
                    }elseif ($res['tipo_id'] == 2) {
                      echo "<a href=\"detalle-local.php?ID=$viID\" class=\"botonMasInfo pull-right\">MÁS INFO</a>";
                    }else {
                      echo "<a href=\"detalle-garaje.php?ID=$viID\" class=\"botonMasInfo pull-right\">MÁS INFO</a>";
                    }
                  ?>
               </div>
               <!-- hasta aqui--->
             </div>
           </div>

         </div>
      </div>
     <?php } endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Son dos cosas muy simples: 1. En PHP tienes que organizar tu respuesta de modo que cuando no haya resultado devuelva en un array una clave llamada por ejemplo `error` y un mensaje con el texto del error. 2. En Ajax, cuando recibes la respuesta, buscar si tiene esa clave, algo así: `if (data.error) {  //poner en el div el mensaje del error } else { //mostrar datos normales}`

Comment: Entonces lo que haga tengo que hacerlo en el php no en el AJAX no?? @A.Cedano

Comment: Tienes que *sincronizarlo* en ambas partes. O sea, PHP y Javascript/Ajax comparten datos. En este caso el dato (JSON) se genera en PHP y es devuelto a Ajax. Por tanto en PHP tienes que construir el JSON de forma que en Ajax sepas cómo verificar si hay algún error en la respuesta. Por lógica eso se hace poniendo dentro del JSON una clave `error` cuando ocurran errores dentro del flujo del programa en PHP. No sé si es muy enredado lo que te digo, si no lo entiendes bien es porque realmente no tienes claro el modo de funcionar de PHP/Ajax y deberías profundizar en ello.